# Ubuntu split Apache2 log files

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

I rencently updated the config of my server to relocate the /var/www and /var/log in the /home folder, i also updated all my virtuals hosts to write the logs in the new /home/log folder.

But now the logs are written inside huge files, one for the error and one for the access and not in form of multiples archived files (like log.1.log, log.2.gz) like before.

How can i restore the log file splitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have changed the location of the logs you should also update configs in `logrotate` cause it still looks for those logs in `/var/log`. I don't know what Linux distro you're using but they should be in `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory

Comment: Thanks, do i need to restart the server after the update of the logrogate file?

Comment: No : Have a look at your crontabs, that's where logrotate is usually triggered

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`. See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/